# Recover removed file from source tree/RubyMine

Tags: rubymine, recover

I have been working on a raketask using Rubymine and Git. I have been using SourceTree to push my changes up to github.

I accidentally chose the "remove" option in source tree for the file I have been working on. This method apparently makes the file "irretrievably lost" which doesn't give me much hope. Is there anyway to recover the file? It was not committed nor pushed up to github yet, and the file is not in my local trash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Restoring a File from Local History](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/restoring-a-file-from-local-history.html).

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, this just happened to me and came upon this.

What I did was (on Windows) right click the directory, properties, and went to previous versions tab. Luckily windows had a backup of just a couple minutes before I deleted it. I was very happy :)